# char* concatenation not working properly

Tags: c++

i recently ran into an issue i wasn't able to find a solutin for till now. I have a function which should act like the String.Concat in C#:

```
char* va(char* Text, ...)
{
    char Buffer[1000];
    va_list parameters;
    va_start(parameters, Text);
    vsprintf(Buffer, Text, parameters);
    return Buffer;
}
```

But for some reason if i do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    AddOption(va("Option %i", i));
```

the menu fields all display "Option 11", so it seems like the text is overwriting. I tried disableing "String Pooling" in the Project Settings, but it didn't change anything! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post `AddOption` code? And what language are you using? Tagged as `C++` but it seems to be `C`.

Comment: Remember the wise words of our forebears: "Thou shalt not return a pointer to an object with automatic storage duration".

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
char *Buffer = new char[1000]
```

For the return of function `char* va()`need a heap variable

Comment: This is not an issue, however returning temporary address of `Buffer[1000]` is obviously wrong.